# Vertical scroll bar on horizontal bar plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, plotly

How can I add vertical scroll bar on horizontal bar chart on plotly? (other open source libraries are also welcome)

I have thousands of horizontal bars in my chart, so I want to scroll up/down on this with a good design.

At the end I want to achieve a plot like below; [image]

Comment: Hi - did you get anywhere with this? I am trying to do the same thing!

Comment: Actually, İ couldn't achieve the exact thing in plotly, because of its zoom feature.